# HttpResponse not working

Tags: android, httpresponse

In the below code the execution is not reaching beyond HttpResponse statement.The Toast before it is displayed but not the one after it.There is no exception.Can anyone tell me why?

I am getting this Uri by picking an image from the gallery and it can even be displayed in an ImageView.So there is no problem with the Uri.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte ar[] = baos.toByteArray();
String s = Base64.encodeBytes(ar);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("My URL");
ArrayList<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", s));
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
Toast.makeText(this, "Upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //  HERE
Toast.makeText(this, "Uploaded or not?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
java.io.InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String result = br.readLine();
```

I have seen some previous questions as well but nothings working.

Comment: Do you see exception in LogCat? Do you run this code in separate thread, because network operations are not allowed on android version > 3.x

Comment: I am running it on version 2.3.6 and there is nothing in the Logcat

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following things :

1. sanity checks: Internet permission in manifest
2. url accessible
3. You are actually reaching the statement after the execute but nothing is there printed that might because you are not doing the readline till the readLine return null

so try this

```
String str=null;

StringBuilder builder =new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader;
reader=new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
while((str=reader.readLine())!=null){

  builder.append(str);
}
Log.v("result",builder.toString());
```